# Running Tensorflow model in Visual Studio just with opencv4

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I made a training model on tensorflow using python and now I would like to run the model in C++ Visual Studio just using OpenCV 4.

1) The frozen_inference_graph.pb that I generate is not usable if I want to run c++ as I made in python ? If not is it possible to save somehow the training ? I mean using the other files model.ckpt.meta/model.ckpt.index or checkpoints to generate again the inference graph and run in C++?

2) Is it possible with the last release of the opencv 4 to run the model without any other programs(C++ API, TensorFlow, Bazel, Eigen3) ? I was running a example code that I found(https://github.com/pirahansiah/opencv4) and it was working normally but when I was using my model I was getting this error

```
OpenCV(4.0.0-dev) Error: Unspecified error (Input layer not found: \
    Preprocessor/map/while/NextIteration) in \
    cv::dnn::dnn4_v20181205::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::connect, \
file C:\opencv\source\opencv-master\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp, \
    line 497
```

printed by `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\TEST\Tensorflow\x64\Debug\Tensorflow.exe`